# Can I use a Google Cloud Storage endpoint for BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I would like to know if it is possible to configure an endpoint(API Endpoint) to Google Cloud Storage for Google BigQuery. For eg: when creating a google cloud storage client with the API endpoint

> client_options = {"api_endpoint": url} storage_client =
> storage.Client(client_options=client_options)

I have looked at it everywhere in the documentation I could not find it. Is this even possible?

The idea is to use the endpoint to get to Google Cloud Storage for all the BigQuery queries.

Thanks and best regards Krishna

Comment: What's a Google Cloud Storage endpoint? any documentation on that?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Can you edit the question and describe in a more detailed way what you want to achieve?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere can you check now. I meant API endpoint. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Prabir can you check now

Comment: Ok, it's not possible. BigQuery can only read file from Cloud Storage. External links (at least URL which aren't GS://) aren't allowed.

Comment: It is still not clear what you exactly want to achieve. Do you want to query data from Cloud Storage? Then you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage). It is not very clear what is the use of API Endpoint here. Can you explain in detail what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere,

> BigQuery can only read file from Cloud Storage. External links (at least URL which aren't GS://) aren't allowed.

This is also evident in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage) shared by @Prabir